# Changing input type number and select tag border color using css

Tags: css

I am trying to change the text color that user types inside text box, and the border of all text boxes from normal to blue.

**EDIT**

I need the text boxes, input number, drop down lists to have a blue border on page load, and the text typed inside is blue too

I tried this:

```
input[type="text"] {
    color: #0090ff;
    border-color: #0090ff;

}
input[type=number]:-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    color: #0090ff;
    border-color: #0090ff;
}

.editor-field select 
 {
    color: #0090ff;
    border-color: #0090ff;
}
```

The problem now that only the input type=text border is blue, but the text isn't, and the input type="number" and the  are not showing any changes.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `:focus` selector.

```css
input[type="text"] {
    color: #0090ff;
    border-color: #0090ff;

}

input[type="text"]:focus {
    color: initial;
    border-color: initial;

}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Comment: No. There still be the part of the text and the select tag

Comment: @droidnation Sorry, I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: I need the text boxes, input number, drop down lists to have a blue border on page load, and the text typed inside is blue too

Comment: @droidnation Ah, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Use `:focus` to when user place value

Working fiddle

**[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/9f2j58w3/)**

```css
input[type="text"] {
color: #0090ff;
border:1px solid #0090ff;

}
input[type=number] {
color: #0090ff;
border:1px solid #0090ff;
}

/* When user focus */

input[type="text"]:focus, input[type=number]:focus, select:focus {
color: tomato;
border:1px solid tomato;
}

select  {
color: #0090ff;
border:1px solid #0090ff;
min-width:150px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<input type="number" name="" id="">
<select>
   <option>1</option>
   <option>1</option>
   <option>1</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: in `select` same approach

Comment: the select stayed as it is and didn't changed at all

Answer (score 0):

```
input[type="text"] {
    color: #0090ff;
    border-color: #0090ff;

}
input[type=number]{
    color: #0090ff;
    border-color: #0090ff;
}
```

Comment: No. There still be the part of the text and the select tag

Comment: I need the text boxes, input number, drop down lists to have a blue border on page load, and the text typed inside is blue too

Comment: just remove `-webkit-inner-spin-button` in css